# Forge API Delete and Re-Create SVF

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

I'm new to the FORGE API,please anyone can tell me is there a way to delete and re-create SVF using a single API call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a [GET](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) request to list, then a [DELETE](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/) request on the manifest endpoint, finally the [POST job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) should create it.

Comment: Thanks Augusto! this helped a lot.Could you please tell me where I can find any sample SVFs related to BIM files